# Blender render compositional framing different from viewport camera view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

[image: Viewport / render comparison]

[image]

Hi There, I'm trying to render out from a scene which has only one camera (the default one).  The render output is giving me an entirely different viewing angle from the camera view in viewport. This isn't a clipping issue - if you move the camera (locked to view) you can see the rooftop geo of the buildings to show it's in the correct place.

The viewport is showing camera view (button zero on numpad), with the passepartout - I've edited this to show a direct comparison below.

There is only one camera in the scene, and this is highlighted in the outliner and zero (Ctrl + Zero too) in the viewport.

Really, quite confused on this - so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not for sure this is your issue, but a common mistake is to assume that since you happen to have only one camera in your scene, you can take it as given that you're always looking through a renderable camera any time you're looking at something in the 3D View. That's not the case. There's the view of your currently active camera, which will be the one that renders, and then there is your current POV in the 3D view, which may or may not correspond to the POV of the active camera at any given moment. What you always see in your outputted renders is the view of the active camera.

Comment: @R-800 Thanks for answering.  How can you tell if the view in 3D view is the view of your currently active camera? I'm using the zero command to navigate between camera perspective view and user perspective, yet the rendered result is way different, almost as if the Camera were positioned much lower in the scene.

Comment: Typically, you'll see a big yellow rectangular frame in view around your scene when you're seeing things through a camera. If you don't see that, you're likely only looking through the 3D view POV, but not through a camera. You can force the currently active camera to take on the same POV as the current 3D view by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Numpad 0.

Comment: @R-800 in that case I definitely am looking through a camera.  It's bizarre, no matter where I move the camera in the scene, the render is always at a point lower than where it's set in Viewport. 

I've tried the timeline to see if there was a keyframe, but there doesn't appear to be.  It seems like the render is offset from the viewport...

Comment: Howabout you share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @R-800 - thanks for taking the time to answer my questions.  I worked out what it was..  one of the displacements on the model was set to render off!  Phew!  Thanks for your help!